# ResNet tuning layers' hyperparameters

Tags: tensorflow, resnet

I recently started working with ResNet, adapting the [official TensorFlow ResNet implementation](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/official/resnet) to run on a custom dataset. I managed to adapt the code to input my own dataset, however, I encountered a problem with the size of the images when I tried running it. My dataset contains 512x512 images, while the baseline implementation was built for (CIFAR10's) 32x32 images. Because of this, in order to run the network I have to change the network's model (the sizes and strides of the layers) so that the network's output size is correct, otherwise the code outputs an error accusing size mismatch. The layers are currently defined as:

```
number of filters: 16
kernel size of the first convolution: 3
stride of the first convolution: 1
size of the first pooling layer: None (currently being skipped)
stride of the first pooling layer: None (currently being skipped)
size of the second pooling layer: 8
stride of the second pooling layer: 1
number of blocks in each block layer: [8, 8, 8]
stride of each block layer: [1, 2, 2]
fully connected layer size: 64
```

I'm new to the field of convolutional neural networks, so I don't know what would be the best way to adapt these layers. I tried a naive approach, increasing each layer slightly to avoid a massive change to a single layer and following a few guidelines I picked from  [here](http://cs231n.github.io/convolutional-networks/).

```
number of filters: 32
kernel size of the first convolution: 7
stride of the first convolution: 2
size of the first pooling layer: 3
stride of the first pooling layer: 2
size of the second pooling layer: 7
stride of the second pooling layer: 1
number of blocks in each block layer: [8, 8, 8, 8]
stride of each block layer: [2, 2, 2, 2]
fully connected layer size: 1024
```

However, with these changes the network does not converge and the loss quickly grows to infinity (e.g. loss is almost 4 million after 100 training steps). Is there a set of guidelines or tips I can use to improve this adaptation?

Any help or tip in this regard will be much appreciated.

Comment: You can compute the output dimensionality of conv layers via the following equation: W=(W−F+2P)/S+1. (S is stride, F is receptive field, P is padding). W is the width/height.

Comment: Thanks. I'm using this equation (and some variants according to tensorflow's padding) to compute the size between the layers. I figured out that I could keep all parameters as default as long as I change the final_size variable to match the output of the previous layer (the second pooling layer), but I'm still open to advice on how can I adapt the layer sizes to improve the network. I'm also unsure if I'm not breaking anything by simply changing the final_size alone to match the output size.

Comment: In my limited experience the thing to do is run multiple experiments w/ varying layer dimensions (pretty obv) and decide :)